# A Silverlight reporting solution where silverlight tables can be scheduled to be delivered as pdf/excel

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-services, export

first of all let me give you the context. I've been asked to create a Silverlight reporting application which allows users to view tables/charts of data and then schedule these controls to be emailed (in pdf or excel format) at a later date when new data becomes available.

I have written an application to do this using webforms for a previous company, essentially the report generation was triggered via a service which executed the web application pages and i was able to generate pdfs from the html strings, however my new company would like a silverlight app and I'm not so sure whether it's possible.

I DO KNOW: That I can use WriteableBitmap to render an image of a report control (ok for PDF), for excel I can use the export to excel functions on various grids.

Questions:

Can I talk to a silverlight app from a windows service and execute methods on the app including rendering controls? (I have a feeling that the client side nature of silverlight may stop me doing this).

If i can execute methods, then i assume that i will be able to intercept an export to excel stream and create an attachment with the excel mime type (if not already set)?

Please don't hit me with "why don't you just use Reporting Services" argument.

I'd be grateful for any comments and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try ActiveReports to accomplish the task you are looking for . ActiveReports does come with a SilverLight report viewer,Windows Forms Viewer and a Web based viewer. ActiveReports also has the ability to create charts and lets you add custom controls to the report.About exporting capabilities ,yes ActiveReports lets you export reports to PDF,Excel,Tiff,RTF,Html etc even on the SilverLight environment.

You can find some information regarding this here:
http://blogs.gcpowertools.co.in/2012/05/exporting-reports-using-active-reports.html